# _.omit is not function

Tags: upgrade

I have just upgraded Wordpress to the latest version (3.5) and it's now throwing me a Javascript error when I try to add a media :

_.omit is not function

Please, any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Re-upload all files, disable all plugins and switch to TwentyEleven. Does it still happen?

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found the issue. It was a problem with my "Nexus" theme.

For anyone with the same issue, I commented out the line "wp_enqueue_script('jquery-prime-options'..." in this function : "option_tree_load"

Answer (score 0):

the solution that worked for me is this:

Open `wp-content/themes/nexus/prime/classes/class.admin.php` and  comment out the line 308:

```
$po_admin->option_tree_load();
```

This seems to have fixed an issue with the “insert media” button not working upon upgrade to WP 3.5

more details here:
[word-press nexus support](http://themeforest.net/item/nexus-responsive-business-wordpress-theme/discussion/2572585?page=24)